# НЕ простые якоря. Как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день! Есть два разных блока. В одном блоке `.chart` - ссылки, в другом блоке `.list` - якоря. Не получается реализовать следующее: чтобы при нажатии на ссылку в блоке `.chart`, блок `.list` прокручивался до нужного якоря. Помогите, пожалуйста. Благодарю!

```js
!function($){
   $(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function () {
        $('.list').animate({ scrollTop:  $('div[data-id="'+this.hash.slice(1)+'"]').offset().top }, 1000 ); 
        return false;
    });
}(jQuery);
```

```css
body {color: black;}

.chart {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  }
.char {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  }

.list {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
.lis {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px;
  }
.pp {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 350px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
<a href="#aaa"><div class="char">a</div></a>
<a href="#bbb"><div class="char">b</div></a>
<a href="#ccc"><div class="char">c</div></a>
<a href="#ddd"><div class="char">d</div></a>
<a href="#eee"><div class="char">e</div></a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="pp"></div>
<div data-id="aaa" class="lis">aaa</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
<div data-id="bbb" class="lis">bbb</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
<div data-id="ccc" class="lis">ccc</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
<div data-id="ddd" class="lis">ddd</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
<div data-id="eee" class="lis">eee</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант ...

```js
!function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var top = $('.list div[data-id="' + $(this).attr("href").slice(1) + '"]')[0].offsetTop - 5;
    $('.list').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1000);
  });
}(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  color: black;
}
.chart {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}
.char {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px 5px;
}
.list {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.lis {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.pp {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <a href="#aaa">
    <div class="char">a</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#bbb">
    <div class="char">b</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#ccc">
    <div class="char">c</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#ddd">
    <div class="char">d</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#eee">
    <div class="char">e</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="aaa" class="lis">aaa</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="bbb" class="lis">bbb</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="ccc" class="lis">ccc</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="ddd" class="lis">ddd</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="eee" class="lis">eee</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function() {
  $('.list').scrollTop(0)
  var x =$('.list div[data-id="' + $(this).attr("href").slice(1) + '"]').position().top;
  $('.list').animate({
    scrollTop: x
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  color: black;
}
.chart {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}
.char {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px 5px;
}
.list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.lis {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.pp {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <a href="#aaa">
    <div class="char">a</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#bbb">
    <div class="char">b</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#ccc">
    <div class="char">c</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#ddd">
    <div class="char">d</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#eee">
    <div class="char">e</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="aaa" class="lis">aaa</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="bbb" class="lis">bbb</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="ccc" class="lis">ccc</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="ddd" class="lis">ddd</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="eee" class="lis">eee</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
</div>
```

**UPD:**

```js
var obj ={
"eee"  : $('.list div[data-id="eee"]').position().top + $('.list div[data-id="eee"]').height() - 100,
"ccc" : $('.list div[data-id="ccc"]').position().top +  $('.list div[data-id="ccc"]').height() - 100,
   "ddd" : $('.list div[data-id="ddd"]').position().top +  $('.list div[data-id="ddd"]').height() -100,
    "aaa" : $('.list div[data-id="aaa"]').position().top +  $('.list div[data-id="aaa"]').height() - 100,
    "bbb" : $('.list div[data-id="bbb"]').position().top +  $('.list div[data-id="bbb"]').height() - 100
   };

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function() {
var x = obj[$(this).attr("href").slice(1)];
  
  $('.list').animate({
    scrollTop: x
  }, 1000);
 

});
```

```css
body {
  color: black;
}
.chart {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}
.char {
  display: block;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px 5px;
}
.list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.lis {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.pp {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <a href="#aaa">
    <div class="char">a</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#bbb">
    <div class="char">b</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#ccc">
    <div class="char">c</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#ddd">
    <div class="char">d</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#eee">
    <div class="char">e</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="aaa" class="lis">aaa</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="bbb" class="lis">bbb</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="ccc" class="lis">ccc</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="ddd" class="lis">ddd</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
  <div data-id="eee" class="lis">eee</div>
  <div class="pp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LADYX добавил новый вариант....

Comment: авто заполнение объекта уж создать))

Comment: @Jean-Claude можно и летающую тарелку за отдельную плату...)))